# iOS: What are the best resources for learning to use Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have been working on the iPhone development for three months now.  I have a fairly decent understanding of Objective-C and iOS,  but I have been putting Interface Builder on the back burner.

I am looking for resources,  preferably non-video as well as video (as my Internet connection is very slow)

What's my best path to getting a handle on this?

Answer (score 0):

I went the same route as you and the Apress book [Beginning iPhone 4 Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430230243) was a great way to start getting your feet wet in IB.